# how to remove item from list using racket programming

Tags: scheme, racket

I am working on a racket program where I need to pass an expression in a list, and return the variables used in that list.

Input:

```
'(A or (B and C))
```

Output:

```
'(A B C)
```

I tried the the below code:

```
(define Remove
  (lambda (L)
    (flatten L)))
```

For input:

```
'(A or (B and C))
```

It returns:

```
'(A or B and C)
```

Now, I want to remove `'or'` and `'and'` here and just want `'(A B C)`.

I tried this:

```
(remove and L)
```

But it's not working.

I really appreciate some suggestions here.

Comment: I got this. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
(define (rm-and-or lst)
  (filter (lambda (x) 
            (and (not (equal? x 'and)) 
                 (not (equal? x 'or)))) 
          (flatten lst)))

(rm-and-or '(A and (B or C))) ==> '(A B C)
```

Flattens the list and filters 'and & 'or out of the result.

Comment: @Rptx well, he calls flatten, I assumed we are working on the result of it.

Comment: He does, inside the procedure. So, to be consistent you could `flatten` the `lst`

Comment: Now more consistent, I guess :)